# OpenLayers - turn off selection of map in IE

Tags: dictionary, selection, openlayers

I have a map in a div, but when a user clicks outside the div and then drags into the map, the map gets selected and turns blue, and it's a bit unsettling to the user who has to click around a number of places before the blue color finally goes away.

I found the following css properties that I can set to none in the .olMap class and this turns selection off for the map in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera, but not in IE.

```
.olMap
{
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
}
```

Does anyone know of another property that could be set like these to turn off selection of the map in IE?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  -ms-user-select: none;  for IE 10+.

For earlier versions of IE try:

```
<div unselectable="on"> </div>
```